# Are OC 3:2 and 3:13 practiced nowadays?

Tags: halacha, bathroom, contemporary-halacha

In OC 3, the Shulchan Aruch discusses many halachos regarding using the bathroom. Many of these seem to be disregarded with the relatively modern invent of the urinal; this is particularly concerning in public restrooms, since most of these halachos are because of *tzni'us*. Specifically:

**Rema, §2:**

> ויסגור הדלת בעדו משום צניעות
>
> He should close the door for himself because of *tzni'us*.

Urinals usually aren't enclosed behind doors.

**SA, §13:**

> לא ישתין מעומד מפני ניצוצות הניתזין על רגליו אם לא שיעמוד במקום גבוה או שישתין לתוך עפר תחוח
>
> One should not urinate while standing because of sprinkles that fall on his legs, if he doesn't stand in a high place or urinate on loose dirt.

The problem here should be obvious.

---

1. Is it actually forbidden to use a urinal for these reasons?
2. If the answer to #1 is "yes," then why do so many shuls and other frum institutions have them?
3. If the answer to #1 is "no," then why?